# Auto-click unmute button in iframe when page loaded

Tags: button, iframe

On this website there's an iframe player that is muted by default. There is also this button that you can click to unmute the video. I need a script for greasyfork user extention to unmute the player when page is loaded.

HTML code of the button is:

```
<button class="unmute" onclick="WSUnmute()">CLICK UNMUTE STREAM</button>
```

I tried various thing I found in google. [This gentleman's script that I edited](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/30683-auto-click/code) for example doesn't work in my case

```
window.onload=function(){
}
function autoClick(){
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("unmute").length>0){
  document.getElementsByClassName("unmute")[0].click();
}
}
```

Edit:
This code when pasted in console     `document.getElementsByClassName("unmute")[0].click();`
does work if I:

1. Load the webpage
2. Open console
3. Click on "Inspect element" and select this button
4. Paste the code - now it works (I don't know why)